# Getting values from object map inside a hash map in jasper reports

Tags: java, dictionary, jasper-reports

I am using a HashMap  field  in jrxml file. The key of the map is an Integer and value is another Hash Map. The second Hash Map key is String and value is object. So I need to retrieve the value of Object. How can I retrieve the value in jrxml file?. For eg below given is my map

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> groupLampMap;
```

where first Integer value is 1, and second Map values will be

```
1)"G","F"
2)"R","S"
3)"A","F".
```

I need to retrieve the value of G,R, A in xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Define you field or parameter with the correct class [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or `HashMap`

```
<field name="groupLampMap" class="java.util.Map"/>
```

Make sure that a `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>>` is passed to parameter or field.

To get the value of for example `G` you use:

```
$F{groupLampMap}.get(1).get("G")
```

Note: this may throw `Nullpointer` if the is no `Map<String,String>` as value on key `1`